# Rails polymorphic naming convention

Tags: ruby-on-rails, naming-conventions, polymorphic-associations

I'm trying to figure out what to name a polymorphic association and not coming up with good options. The class that will contain the polymorphic association is called `LicenseBatch`, and if it weren't polymorphic, the foreign key would just be `owner_id`. It seems that the go-to polymorphic name would be `ownerable`, but what if I have another class that is ownable? I'd like this to be more specific, but things like `batch_ownerable` sound awkward.

Any suggestions or similar situations you have seen before?

Comment: in the polymorphic associate you have to use `_type` and `_id` suffixes. for instance if you have `image` table that is shared by different models then you will use the polymorphic association I normally use `linkage` word like `linkage_type` and `linkage_id`

Comment: I would go with `license_batchee` because it makes it immediately apparent what model it refers to from the other side of the association. -ee is added to nouns to mean a person somehow associated with the object denoted by the noun.

Comment: thanks Moustafa, I'm aware of that. my question is more along the lines of figuring out a better name than `ownerable_id` and `ownerable_type`. I'm worried that in a large application I may run into something else that is ownerable, and it will cause conflicts

Comment: ownerable? I doubt it makes any sense to use words like that. I think 'linkage' makes much more sense

Answer (score 3):

Try to put a name that automatically refers to the model name, so if the model is Comment I would use commentable_type and commentable_id. For this specific case I would use:

licensable_batch_type and licensable_batch_id